# What does VC-WIN32-ONECORE in OpenSSL mean?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, openssl, .net-5

I downloaded [openssl-1.1.1i.tar.gz](https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1i.tar.gz) and run "perl configure list" in "Visual Studio 2019 Tools Command Prompt". then it displayed:

```
Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.1i (0x1010109fL) for list
Using os-specific seed configuration
Usage: Configure [no-<cipher> ...] [enable-<cipher> ...] [-Dxxx] [-lxxx] [-Lxxx] [-fxxx] [-Kxxx] [no-hw-xxx|no-hw] [[no-]threads] [[no-]shared] [[no-]zlib|zlib-dynamic] [no-asm] [no-egd] [sctp] [386] [--prefix=DIR] [--openssldir=OPENSSLDIR] [--with-xxx[=vvv]] [--config=FILE] os/compiler[:flags]

pick os/compiler from:
BS2000-OSD BSD-generic32 BSD-generic64 BSD-ia64 BSD-sparc64 BSD-sparcv8
BSD-x86 BSD-x86-elf BSD-x86_64 Cygwin Cygwin-i386 Cygwin-i486 Cygwin-i586
Cygwin-i686 Cygwin-x86 Cygwin-x86_64 DJGPP MPE/iX-gcc UEFI UWIN VC-CE VC-WIN32
VC-WIN32-ARM VC-WIN32-ONECORE VC-WIN64-ARM VC-WIN64A VC-WIN64A-ONECORE
VC-WIN64A-masm VC-WIN64I aix-cc aix-gcc aix64-cc aix64-gcc android-arm
android-arm64 android-armeabi android-mips android-mips64 android-x86
android-x86_64 android64 android64-aarch64 android64-mips64 android64-x86_64
bsdi-elf-gcc cc darwin-i386-cc darwin-ppc-cc darwin64-arm64-cc darwin64-ppc-cc
darwin64-x86_64-cc gcc haiku-x86 haiku-x86_64 hpux-ia64-cc hpux-ia64-gcc
hpux-parisc-cc hpux-parisc-gcc hpux-parisc1_1-cc hpux-parisc1_1-gcc
hpux64-ia64-cc hpux64-ia64-gcc hpux64-parisc2-cc hpux64-parisc2-gcc hurd-x86
ios-cross ios-xcrun ios64-cross ios64-xcrun iossimulator-xcrun iphoneos-cross
irix-mips3-cc irix-mips3-gcc irix64-mips4-cc irix64-mips4-gcc linux-aarch64
linux-alpha-gcc linux-aout linux-arm64ilp32 linux-armv4 linux-c64xplus
linux-elf linux-generic32 linux-generic64 linux-ia64 linux-mips32 linux-mips64
linux-ppc linux-ppc64 linux-ppc64le linux-sparcv8 linux-sparcv9 linux-x32
linux-x86 linux-x86-clang linux-x86_64 linux-x86_64-clang linux32-s390x
linux64-mips64 linux64-s390x linux64-sparcv9 mingw mingw64 nextstep
nextstep3.3 sco5-cc sco5-gcc solaris-sparcv7-cc solaris-sparcv7-gcc
solaris-sparcv8-cc solaris-sparcv8-gcc solaris-sparcv9-cc solaris-sparcv9-gcc
solaris-x86-gcc solaris64-sparcv9-cc solaris64-sparcv9-gcc solaris64-x86_64-cc
solaris64-x86_64-gcc tru64-alpha-cc tru64-alpha-gcc uClinux-dist
uClinux-dist64 unixware-2.0 unixware-2.1 unixware-7 unixware-7-gcc vms-alpha
vms-alpha-p32 vms-alpha-p64 vms-ia64 vms-ia64-p32 vms-ia64-p64 vos-gcc
vxworks-mips vxworks-ppc405 vxworks-ppc60x vxworks-ppc750 vxworks-ppc750-debug
vxworks-ppc860 vxworks-ppcgen vxworks-simlinux

NOTE: If in doubt, on Unix-ish systems use './config'.
```

I saw "VC-WIN32-ONECORE", but i don't know what it means. Does it mean it compiles for ".Net Core" or "UWP"? What's the difference between “VC-WIN32” and “VC-WIN32-ONECORE”?

And i found [Improve the Windows OneCore target support #7729](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/7729), why can not i see the following targets in the configure list?

```
VC-WIN32-UWP
VC-WIN64A-UWP
VC-WIN32-ARM-UWP
VC-WIN64-ARM-UWP
```

Are these the same with VC-WIN32-ONECORE and VC-WIN64A-ONECORE?

Answer (score 1):

According to OpenSSL source code **OPENSSL_SYS_WIN_CORE** only affect file  **openssl\crypto\cryptlib.c**. So it seems forbid interaction with user via GUI.